# Cannot connect to dbdash from DataGrip

Tags: jetbrains-ide, dashdb, datagrip

In DataGrip, I'm using the DB2 (JTOpen) data source/driver and supplying the connection information directly off of the dashdb "connect" tab. When trying to connect to my dashdb, I keep getting the following error:

[image]

I am using the stock information as supplied on the "Connect" tab of the dashDB dashboard:

[image]

Has anyone been successful connected to dashDB with DataGrip?

Comment: Could you post any more information on what part of the connection information you used? How has it been configured? Why are you using JTOpen and not the DB2 LUW connection type?

Comment: Should I use JTOpen or DB2 LUW? Does this scenario work? Has it ever been tested?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

dashDB shares technology with DB2 LUW and you need to use the DB2 LUW-specific connection type, not the one for DB2 on IBM i (AS/400). dashDB has been successfully tested with all kinds of tools.

Try `jdbc:db2://...`